# IPOPT optimizer signal handler TypeError

Tags: openmdao, ipopt

I am getting the following error while using IPOPT from pyOptSparse in OpenMDAO.
I followed pyoptsparse documentations to install pyOptSparse with IPOPT which went very smooth. 
The SLSQP optimizer works perfect but IPOPT gives this error. 
Thank you
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAf23.jpg)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using ubuntu 20 in google cloud.

Comment: Please refer to [1] in the port or  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAf23.jpg for the error message

Comment: What version of OpenMDAO and pyoptsparse are you using?  We recently (as in within a couple of weeks) started supporting pyoptsparse > 2.0 in OpenMDAO.  I think we addressed this with the latest release (3.1.1) of OpenMDAO but I could be wrong.

Comment: The details of versions are as follows:  python = 3.8
OpenMDAO = 3.1.1
pyOptSparse = 2.1.1
Ipopt = 3.11.7 (as recommended in docs of pyOptSparse) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something is getting messed up with the user termination signal. To investigate though, it will help if you can provide the vesion information that rfalck asked for.

The pyoptsparse driver, when used with SNOPT, supports "clean termination" which means you can send use "kill -SIGUSR1 pid" with your run process ID to terminate, and it will still clean up and give a summary.  IPOPT doesn't support this, nor does SLSQP.  We generally don't have any problems with SLSQP or IPOPT, but maybe some combination of your OS and IPOPT is causing a hiccup.

As a workaround, try the following setting:

```
 prob.driver.options['user_terminate_signal'] = None
```

That should turn off any of the signal caching and cleanup code.  The error you got occured after the optimization finished, so you are almost there.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am using python = 3.8 OpenMDAO = 3.1.1 pyOptSparse = 2.1.1 Ipopt = 3.11.7 (as recommended in docs of pyOptSparse). The workaround of `['user_terminate_signal']` gave another error: `KeyError: "pyOptSparseDriver: Option 'user_terminate_signal' cannot be set because it has not been declared."` . 
But unlike you mentioned of finished optimization, it has not called objective even once.
I request to provide appropriate combination of OS and versions of other package, I can work with those easily since I am using cloud machine.

Comment: Oh my, we've got a horrible typo in the options.  Try "user_teriminate_signal" now, but we are going to fix it quickly.

Comment: Yes, after using "user_teriminate_signal",  TypeError posted above is not shown, however optimizer is not performing any iterations neither.

Comment: I had that happen the first couple of times I used IPOPT, and the problem was with the options that were being passed in to IPOPT.  OpenMDAO runs with these options: DEFAULT_OPT_SETTINGS['IPOPT'] = {
    'hessian_approximation': 'limited-memory',
    'nlp_scaling_method': 'user-scaling',
    'linear_solver': 'mumps'
}

Comment: However, i think pyoptsparse might insert a few additional ones.  It seems like option errors never get reported back to openmdao, but the "symptom" is you never even evaluate any objectives.  More info on options here:  https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html

Comment: Are you able to run a simple optimization example, like the paraboloid optimization, using IPOPT?  http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/basic_guide/first_optimization.html

Comment: @RobFalck when I ran the paraboloid it only returned the initial values in the standard output format of pyoptsparse with 0 calls to the objective function. SLSQP however solves it completely. 
@KennethMoore Thanks for the insight to setting of the options. I wonder if signal error has anything to do with unablity to import petsc4py, I couldn't install petsc as it was giving `  Failed building wheel for petsc  `, although "wheel" is already installed.